# Smoking Cigarette

Tags: halal-haram, salat, fatwa, makruh

My Question : Does smoking Cigarette  invalidate prayer for 40 days? I am not chain smoker but I need to smoke only before toilet ..I do not go for mosque or prayer after smoking ..pls answer my question

Comment: Who said: «Smoking Cigarettes invalidates prayer for 40 days» It invalidates fasting...